# How to use nearest neighbor in canvas while resizing

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I have a discord bot that creates a 20x20 photo I want it to increase the size but it becomes blury and bad
(discord bot dont use css)

I tried to increase by the normal way from height and width but it becomes blury

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer you should use imageSmoothingEnabled method

```
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false
```